# How do I connect a 3rd party XMPP client to Cisco's Jabber Video?

Tags: xmpp, jabber, cisco-jabber

[Cisco's Jabber Video](https://www.ciscojabbervideo.com/) client does not support Linux. I would like to connect to the rest of my company's users with a 3rd party XMPP client like Pidgin. Is this possible?

The setup terminology is slightly different which is also confusing.

Jabber video setup screen:

[image]

Pidgin setup screens:

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions how to go about this? Filling in the various fields in Pidgin so far has not been successful, but perhaps I'm missing something...

Comment: after i did all mentioned in that article - it works for me
http://csh.us/2012/07/09/pidgin-support-for-cisco-webex-im/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To save people time:

> Cisco Webex Connect IM uses Jabber as its chat protocol, so Pidgin (or any Jabber client) should be able to work with it. Here’s how to
> configure a Webex Connect account in Pidgin:
>
> ```
> XMPP protocol
>     Basic tab
>         Username: first part of your Webex username before the @domain
>         Domain: the part of your webex username after the @ sign.
>         Resource: blank
>         Password: your Webex IM password
>         Local alias: whatever you want to show up for you locally in
>             the chat window when you send messages, such as your
>             username, instead of the lengthy Jabber ID string
>     Advanced tab
>         Connect port: 5222
>         Connect server: c2s.<your domain>.webexconnect.com
> ```
>
> Jabber (and obviously Pidgin) has conference/chat room support, and so
> does Webex Connect via a custom conference server:
>
> ```
> Buddies menu: Join a chat
>     Account: choose the XMPP Webex account
>     Room name: whatever you want, or a known existing one
>     Server: conference.isj1.webex.com (should already be filled in)
>     Handle: whatever username you want
> Inviting people once in the room:
>     Conversation menu: Invite
>     Buddy: enter their email address. Should show a list of matching names to select and invite.
> ```

Source:
https://web.archive.org/web/20160917231224/http://csh.us/2012/07/09/pidgin-support-for-cisco-webex-im/